# Summing Values automatically in Bar Chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a simple barchart on some data.

I've got a list of values x:

`objective_values = np.array([ 0., -1., -1.,  0., -1.,  0.,  0.,  3., -1., -2., -2., -1.,  0.,  1. , 1.,  4.])`

and associated probabilities:
`probabilites =  np.array([0.05664819, 0.09759888, 0.09759888 ,0.02133367, 0.14491666, 0.03902614, 0.03902614, 0.00385143, 0.08802889, 0.15658646, 0.15658646, 0.03704651, 0.04752267, 0.00210716, 0.00210716, 0.01001469])`

which I'm trying to whack into a barchart together. However, when I do the simple code

```
objective,probabilities,objective_values = compute_mwis_energy_sv_bar_chart(statevector,G)

plt.bar(objective_values,probabilities)
```

Matplot doesn't sum the ordered probabilities I.e the value of -2 is 0.156, not 0.30. I've scoured all over but I can't find a way to do this simply - am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .zip() to create a dictionary where you yourself sum up the probabilities for each objective value. Then pass that on to matplotlib

```
sums = {}
for key, value in zip(objective_values, probabilites):
    try:
        sums[key] += value
    except KeyError:
        sums[key] = value
print(sums)
```

Sums would be

```
{0.0: 0.20355680999999998, -1.0: 0.46518982000000003, 3.0: 0.00385143, -2.0: 0.31317292, 1.0: 0.00421432, 4.0: 0.01001469}
```

Then get the keys and values to get the lists

```
objective_values = list(sums.keys())
probabilites = list(sums.values())
```

This will give you

```
([0.0, -1.0, 3.0, -2.0, 1.0, 4.0],
 [0.20355680999999998,
  0.46518982000000003,
  0.00385143,
  0.31317292,
  0.00421432,
  0.01001469])
```

Answer (score 2):

To add onto @Shubham Periwal's answer, if you are willing to use(have access to) the pandas library, you can probably do it in a line:

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.DataFrame(
        [(x, y) for x, y in zip(objective_values, probabilites)]
        ).groupby(0) \
         .sum() \
         .reset_index()
```

Then, you can plot your bar chart with:

```
plt.bar(df[0], df[1])
```

[image]

This example isn't formatted but you can add in logic to rename your columns and chart features properly.

Comment: Ah I thought there would be a way through Pandas ! I'm an R guy myself for this sort of thing normally so wasn't sure !